# Properly display the legend of a 4 panel distribution plot with fitdistrplus in R

Tags: r, plot

I am using the `fitdistrplus` package in R and trying to make a nice, 4-panel distribution plot, like in the authors' published paper (J. of Statistical Software, vol. 64, issue 4):

[image: Delignette-Muller et al., 2015]

However, when I use the same code that they present in their paper the text values associated with different color-coded lines/curves are just placed arbitrarily and you can't tell which color corresponds to which series:

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
plot.legend <- c("Weibull", "lognormal", "gamma")
denscomp(list(fw, fln, fg), legendtext = plot.legend)
qqcomp(list(fw, fln, fg), legendtext = plot.legend)
cdfcomp(list(fw, fln, fg), legendtext = plot.legend)
ppcomp(list(fw, fln, fg), legendtext = plot.legend)
```

[image: Real world version]

I also tried it with the `,  xlegend = "bottomright"` option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the legend to be visible in each plot you could manually manipulate the location. Some example code is provided below. Also, scaling the legend using `cex` will avoid the legend overlapping a large portion of the plot. The exact legend positions would be based on your data.

```
library(fitdistrplus)
x <- exp(rnorm(100,0,1))

fw <- fitdist(x,distr="weibull")
fln <- fitdist(x,distr="lnorm")
fg <- fitdist(x,distr="gamma")


par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
plot.legend <- c("Weibull", "lognormal", "gamma")
denscomp(list(fw, fln, fg)
         , legendtext = plot.legend
         ,xlegend=10
         ,ylegend=0.5
         ,cex=0.7)
qqcomp(list(fw, fln, fg)
       , legendtext = plot.legend
       ,xlegend=8
       ,ylegend=6
       ,cex=0.7)
cdfcomp(list(fw, fln, fg)
        , legendtext = plot.legend
        ,xlegend=8
        ,ylegend=0.3
        ,cex=0.7)
ppcomp(list(fw, fln, fg)
       , legendtext = plot.legend
       ,xlegend=0.7
       ,ylegend=0.3
       ,cex=0.7)
```

[image]